# What is the most efficient way to manipulate matplotlib figure components of many different plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib

For my matplotlib-powered projects I often create many different graphs. For each of these graphs I am typically editing quite of bunch of the same figure components (e.g., tick marks, labels, titles, legends etc.). However, with many graphs this typically makes for very long scripts in which I essentially do the same thing over and over again for each of the graphs.

So my question is: what is the best approach to make this more efficient ?

I think creating a function to which I pass the ax of my plot along with the arguments for the individual components would be a good approach. To prevent the function of having hundreds of key words to ensure that each variable is assigned to the correct figure component, I was thinking to use *args/**kwargs. However, I don't know how to make sure that, for example, the keywords for the legend method ends up in the legend method and not the title method.

Comment: All text and no sample code is a poor practice of asking questions on SO. Since you seem to be new to Stack Overflow, please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You can either use matplotlib styles or write helper functions around your customization.